# Problema con certificados: Cannot recover key

Tags: java, spring-boot, certificado-ssl, keystore

estamos teniendo un problema en nuestra aplicación con los certificados, os cuento.

Tenemos configurado en la aplicación el certificado de la siguiente manera:

```
key-store: file:/usr/share/tomcat7/conf/certif/certificado.jks
key-store-password: PASSWORD_XX
```

Hasta hace un mes, el certificado funcionaba correctamente, pero se caducó, por tanto al equipo de sistemas le pedimos un nuevo certificado y que por favor, lo pusieran en la misma ruta y con la misma password.

En principio el equipo de sistemas ya ha puesto el nuevo certificado vigente y con la misma password, pues cuando la aplicacion trata el certificado da el siguiente error

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

En principio ese error es porque la contraseña del almacen de claves no coincide con la nuestra.... El código en cuestión es este:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

        ks.load(keyStore.getInputStream(), keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

        LOGGER.info("Loaded keystore: " + keyStore.getURI().toString()); (este log se muestra, por tanto el ks.load lo hace bien)
        try {
            keyStore.getInputStream().close(); (Aqui entiendo que cierra el fichero .jks que ha cogido para leer)

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(ks, keyStorePassword.toCharArray()); (creo que podría fallar aquí, al iniciar el fichero .jks y al ponerle la password, ya que lo siguiente en el log es el error arriba comentado)

HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
        messageSender.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers());
```

Me he descargado los dos certificados del servidor (el caducado y el nuevo) y los he abierto con el siguiente comando

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

Al pedirme la contraseña, he puesto la que tenemos configurada en la aplicación, en la propiedad keystore-password (PASSWORD_XX), y los dos certificados me los ha a listado, **por tanto entiendo que la contraseña es correcta**

Lo que he visto raro al abrir el certificado nuevo (el vigente) es que sale este warning, en cambio en el certificado ya caducado no sale el warning al listarlo con el comando

```
    *****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* La integridad de la información almacenada en el almacén de claves  *
* NO se ha comprobado.  Para comprobar dicha integridad, *
* debe proporcionar la contraseña del almacén de claves.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
```

Además, el nuevo certificado (el vigente), contiene 2 entradas, una entrada es el certificado vigente, y la otra entrada es el certificado antiguo, ¿esto podría dar problemas?

Si en principio la contraseña es correcta (porque puedo ver los certificados del .jks), porque se puede producir ese error?

Muchas gracias!

Un saludo.

Comment: Prueba verificar la contraseña del keystore para validar que sea la misma que la del certificado `keytool -list -keystore .keystore` de esta forma te solicitaría la contraseña del keystore.

Comment: Las veces que ese mensaje me ha salido a mi fueron hacer ese comando y no ingresar la password. Con lo que muestra las entradas pero nada más. Es más la última oración lo dice clarito: "Para comprobar dicha integridad, debe proporcionar la contraseña del almacén de claves."

Comment: Buenas, Como puse en la pregunta, la clave la comprobé, me descargué los .jks y con el comando keytools me pidio ingresar la clave, puse la que tenemos configurada en el backend y se me mostraban los certificados correctamente, por tanto entiendo que la clave puesta en el el .jks es correcta.

Comment: Esto también pasa cuando generas el .jks con la contraseña por defecto prueba utilizar `changeit` que es por defecto en java, por eso lanza que no puede comprobar la integridad, porque tiene la contraseña por defecto y colocas una diferente.

Comment: Hola Roberto, pero porque dices que tiene una password diferente? es decir, yo uso el comando keytool para listar el certificado que contiene el .jks y me pide una password, pongo la que tenemos en codigo y el keytool me muestra el certificado correctamente, entiendo que el trozo de código que he puesto hace lo mismo, abre el .jks y pone la contraseña que está configurada en el .yml, Si el .keystore tuviera una password diferente el keytool me daria un error, ¿no? Gracias!

Comment: He probado a usar el comando keytool y poner una password erronea "aaa" y me salta este error: "error de herramienta de claves: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect". Por tanto entiendo que al poner la contraseña correcta (la misma que hay en código configurada) me muestra los certificados que hay en el almacen de claves porque la clave coincide, pero luego cuando lo hace el backend da el error que puse en la pregunta..(Cannot recover key)

Comment: Buenas, he probado a usar una interfaz grafica para los .jks (KeyStore explorer), he abierto el .jks que está en el servidor y el programa me pide contraseña... he puesto la contraseña que está configurada en las propiedades del servidor y me abre correctamente la interfaz... por tanto entiendo que las contraseñas están bien puestas en el .jks.. ¿a que se puede deber que en el servidor me de el error de Cannot recover key?

Answer (score 3):

ayer dimos con la solución, la pongo por aquí por si a alguien más le pasa.

Tras comprobar que la contraseña del .jks (almacen de claves) era correcta (la que teniamos configurada en el código era la que habian configurado en el .jks), detectamos que la **contraseña del certificado dentro del .jks debe de ser igual que la del .jks**. Tras poner la misma contraseña en el .jks y en el certificado dentro del .jks, funcionó todo correctamente.

Este comando es para poner contraseña al almacen de claves

```
keytool -storepasswd -new [insert new keystore password] -keystore [insert keystore file name]
```

Este comando es para poner contraseña al certificado (mediante el alias)

```
keytool -keypasswd -alias [insert alias] -new [insert new key password] -keystore [insert keystore file name]
```

La forma en la que ví que era diferente contraseña, fue mediante el programa **KeyStore Explorer**, de esta forma, ví que al abrir el certificado del almacen de claves me pedía contraseña y la que ponía era incorrecta.

Un saludo y gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Me he encontrado con este problema, y tu solución me ha hecho abrir los ojos, me he dado cuenta que tampoco cargaba la password de la key que generalmente es diferente a la password de la keystore.  Viendo bien mi codigo me di cuenta que igual que cargo el alias del certificado con una properties la clave se carga con una clase:

```html
outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, ClientPasswordCallbackHandler.class.getName());
```

Esa clase contiene el identidicador de la key y su clave correspondiente, así te quitas la limitación de que sea la password igual tanto para la keystore como para el certificado y además ganas es seguridad.

```html
public class ClientPasswordCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedCallbackException {

        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {

            WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i];

            if (pc.getUsage() == WSPasswordCallback.SIGNATURE
                    || pc.getUsage() == WSPasswordCallback.DECRYPT)

                if (pc.getIdentifier().equals(ALIASCERTIFICADO)) {

                    pc.setPassword(CLAVECERTIFICADO);
                }
        }

    }
}
```